# What is the easiest way to style the ScrollViewer in XAML

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I would like style my ScrollViewer (background, arrows...)
What is the easiest way to do that?

Has someone a couple of good and simply examples for this?

(the article from sachabarber know it, but for my purposes too complex)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the easiest way would be to have [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) and edit the ScrollViewer styles with the Blend GUI designer.

That being said, I as a programmer would stil prefer to style it by hand, as in the article by Sacha Barber.

Answer (score 0):

Here http://blog.xamltemplates.net/?p=10 a small tutorial.